# Javascript for showing image on mouseover

Tags: javascript, jquery

Please see this [link](http://www.fotolia.com).

How images are showing large on mouseover according to the position of mouse and screen scrolling?

Can any one provide the same script for this purpose.

Thanx in advance

Comment: you need to use any jQeury plugin for this

Comment: I believe anything that we don't know is a question.

Answer (score 2):

If you use [jquery](http://docs.jquery.com/Downloading_jQuery) it is quite easy.

Here is a tutorial: [Easiest Tooltip and Image Preview Using jQuery.](http://cssglobe.com/post/1695/easiest-tooltip-and-image-preview-using-jquery)

Here is the actual `JS` code from the site above (note you need [jquery](http://docs.jquery.com/Downloading_jQuery) for this)

```
/*
 * Image preview script 
 * powered by jQuery (http://www.jquery.com)
 * 
 * written by Alen Grakalic (http://cssglobe.com)
 * 
 * for more info visit http://cssglobe.com/post/1695/easiest-tooltip-and-image-preview-using-jquery
 *
 */

this.imagePreview = function(){ 
    /* CONFIG */

        xOffset = 10;
        yOffset = 30;

        // these 2 variable determine popup's distance from the cursor
        // you might want to adjust to get the right result

    /* END CONFIG */
    $("a.preview").hover(function(e){
        this.t = this.title;
        this.title = "";    
        var c = (this.t != "") ? "<br/>" + this.t : "";
        $("body").append("<p id='preview'><img src='"+ this.href +"' alt='Image preview' />"+ c +"</p>");                                
        $("#preview")
            .css("top",(e.pageY - xOffset) + "px")
            .css("left",(e.pageX + yOffset) + "px")
            .fadeIn("fast");                        
    },
    function(){
        this.title = this.t;    
        $("#preview").remove();
    }); 
    $("a.preview").mousemove(function(e){
        $("#preview")
            .css("top",(e.pageY - xOffset) + "px")
            .css("left",(e.pageX + yOffset) + "px");
    });         
};


// starting the script on page load
$(document).ready(function(){
    imagePreview();
});
```

and here is the relevant html segment

```
    <ul>
        <li><a href="1.jpg" class="preview"><img src="1s.jpg" alt="gallery thumbnail" /></a></li>
        <li><a href="2.jpg" class="preview"><img src="2s.jpg" alt="gallery thumbnail" /></a></li>
        <li><a href="3.jpg" class="preview"><img src="3s.jpg" alt="gallery thumbnail" /></a></li>
        <li><a href="4.jpg" class="preview"><img src="4s.jpg" alt="gallery thumbnail" /></a></li>
    </ul>
```

Comment: James, But the problem in the jquery is that if the images are at bottum of page then the large image view go down under the screen, I want that the large image will automatically adjust its position according to its position on page

Comment: you could play around with offset() to set the desired distance from edges and so.

Comment: Can you please suggest me how to do this? Actuly I am very new to jquery

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at: http://www.mind-projects.it/projects/jqzoom/